# How to drop/remove duplicate columns in pyspark?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, databricks

```
df =

Gds Mds  Score  Mds   Ndl    Ndl
23  56   24.56  null  61    null
45  456  77     null  76    null
59  46   47.5   null  34    null
```

This is my df dataframe. Here we can see two column has been duplicated Mds and Ndl so I want to remove that column.

I want output like

```
output =

Gds Mds  Score  Ndl 
23  56   24.56  61   
45  456  77     76   
59  46   47.5   34
```

Comment: On what criteria you want to remove these duplicate columns, is it because of having `null` values ?

Comment: @DKNY - Yes, Exactly

Comment: In that case, is there a rationale behind keeping those columns with same name ? I'm trying to understand the use case here!

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is the columns with repeated names and you get ambiguous error messages. Also, I don't know if `null`is a string of if it should be `None` but let's say you have this df in spark:

```
df  = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
('23','56','24.56','null','61','null'),
('45','456','77','null','76','null'),
('59','46','47.5','null','34','null')
  ], ['Gds','Mds','Score','Mds','Ndl','Ndl'])

+---+---+-----+----+---+----+
|Gds|Mds|Score| Mds|Ndl| Ndl|
+---+---+-----+----+---+----+
| 23| 56|24.56|null| 61|null|
| 45|456|   77|null| 76|null|
| 59| 46| 47.5|null| 34|null|
+---+---+-----+----+---+----+
```

Then, let's get the schema from this df and add a `'_bis'` suffix to the repeated column names. This was done by considering there are only two columns with the same name but it can be adapted when a column is observed more than 2 times.

That done, let's create a new dfwith the modified schema and do a union with the original df (that will allow to have a df with unique column names):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

cols = df.schema.names

for i in range(len(cols)):
    if cols.count(cols[i])>1:
        df.schema[i].name = cols[i]+'_bis'
        cols[i] = cols[i]+'_bis'
  
output = spark.createDataFrame([], df.schema).union(df)

output.show()

+---+-------+-----+----+-------+----+
|Gds|Mds_bis|Score| Mds|Ndl_bis| Ndl|
+---+-------+-----+----+-------+----+
| 23|     56|24.56|null|     61|null|
| 45|    456|   77|null|     76|null|
| 59|     46| 47.5|null|     34|null|
+---+-------+-----+----+-------+----+
```

Finally, looping though the column. If there is a correspondent `_bis`, then eliminate the one with `nulls`and eliminate the `_bis` suffix:

```
for col in output.columns:
    if col+'_bis' in output.columns:
        if output.select(col).distinct().collect()[0][0] == 'null':
            output = output.drop(col).withColumnRenamed(col+'_bis',col)
        else:
            output.drop(col+'_bis')
    elif col[-4:] == '_bis'and col.replace('_bis', '') in output.columns:
        if output.select(col).distinct().collect()[0][0] == 'null':
            output = output.drop(col).withColumnRenamed(col+'_bis',col)
        else:
            output.drop(col+'_bis')
        
        
output.show()

+---+---+-----+---+
|Gds|Mds|Score|Ndl|
+---+---+-----+---+
| 23| 56|24.56| 61|
| 45|456|   77| 76|
| 59| 46| 47.5| 34|
+---+---+-----+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would solve the problem.

```
cols= [] 
seen = set()
for c in df.columns:
    cols.append('{}_dup'.format(c) if c in seen else c)
    seen.add(c)
df.toDF(*cols).select(*[c for c in cols if not c.endswith('_dup')])
```

Comment: This is will not work, if the column position containing `null` values is swaped with the one containing non-null values.